# Every open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable intersection of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove using topological properties that every open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable intersection of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$? Is that true that every closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable intersection of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$?

I have seen several divergent responses for those questions and I have no idea of how to answer to these statements.

Comment: Well, since every open interval is already an open subset of $\Bbb R$…

Comment: An open iterval is OPEN, so no need of countable many, only one is needed. For closed sets, YES, you need countable many.,

Comment: Thanks! @TitoEliatron .

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Do you have any tip to help me to prove this second statement?

Comment: Surely you mean to ask if any open set is a countable intersection of intervals?

Comment: No. How can I prove that for a closed set, it can be expressed as a countable intersection of intervals? @RomainS.

Comment: @Manatee see the answer by William Elliot below, you essentially write a closed interval as the intersection of shrinking open intervals.

Comment: @RomainS I got it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$[a,b] = \cap\{ (u,v) : u,v \in \mathbb{Q}, u < a, b < v \}$$

In a simular way you can prove the dual statement that every open interval is a countable union of closed sets.

Comment: I didn't understand where this is going. :(

Comment: Why do I take $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Manatee it's a countable set (so the intersection is countable). And it works because it's a dense set too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Are both inclusions easy to show? 
$[a,b]\subset$ the intersection and the intersection $\subset[a,b]$?

Comment: @Manatee Yes, IMHO.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can you give me a tip?

Comment: @Manatee think seriously about it, would be my tip.